# How to force Chrome/Firefox to go to this url " blabla:// " when i type it in adress bar and not search " blabla:// " in google?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

How to force Chrome/Firefox to go to this url " blabla:// " when i type it in adress bar and not search " blabla:// " in google ?

i want same result as :

```
<a href="blabla://">link</a>
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

solved my problem myself, i just type blabla://x and the navigator doesnt search it in google